# How to mount .pgpass file in docker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, amazon-redshift

I have `test_main_file.py` and dockerfile in my project. There is a line in `test_main_file.py`

```
redshift= open(os.environ['Home'] + '/.pgpass','r').readline()
```

which is nothing but redshift database information.

Now I am running above .py file in docker but I am getting following error:

```
redshift = open(os.environ['HOME'] + '/.pgpass', 'r').readline() 
              IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/root/.pgpass'
```

My docker command is:

```
docker run --volume ~/.aws:/root/.aws --volume ~/Users/mmarvania/.pgpass:/root/.pgpass docker5
```

FYI: my `.pgpass` file is in `/Users/mmarvania/` directory in my mac.

Comment: Is .pgpass a file or folder. If it is a file, map the folder which contains .pgpass file to a folder inside the container. Then access the file inside that folder.

    `docker run --volume ~/.aws:/root/.aws --volume ~/Users/mmarvania:/root/config docker5`


The access the file like this:

    `redshift = open(os.environ['HOME'] + '/config/.pgpass', 'r').readline()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is working !!!!

Comment: And what if I want to run this docker on AWS using ECS and EC2? How to handle .pgpass file in this case? Because redshift = open(os.environ['HOME'] + '/config/.pgpass', 'r').readline()  will throw an error since my .pgpass file is in local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a file, map the folder which contains .pgpass file to a folder inside the container. Then access the file inside that folder. docker run --volume ~/.aws:/root/.aws --volume ~/Users/mmarvania:/root/config docker5 The access the file like this: redshift = open(os.environ['HOME'] + '/config/.pgpass', 'r').readline()